# Lead Trigger on Import

Tags: trigger, leads, import

Hi I have a trigger that runs to dedupe leads that have matching phone numbers(we have 2 phone fields) it works when you go and manually create a lead in Salesforce but when using dataloader.io it doesn't always recognize dupes and just runs the 'else if' and below(not including the whole trigger in this thread on purpose). Is this a problem with the trigger or Dataloader?

```
trigger LeadTrigger on Lead (before insert, after insert, after update) {
    DateTime datetoSearch = DateTime.now().addDays(-14);
    List<Opportunity> oppList = New List<Opportunity>();
    List<Lead> leadList = New List<Lead>();
    List<Database.LeadConvert> lConverts = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();


    if(Trigger.isBefore){
        if(Trigger.isInsert){

            for(Lead toProcess : trigger.new){
                boolean isCheck = false;               
                system.debug('toProcess.PostalCode: '+toProcess.PostalCode);
                system.debug('toProcess.State: '+toProcess.State);

                if(toProcess.Phone != null || toProcess.MobilePhone != null){
                    Lead[] existLead = [SELECT Id FROM Lead WHERE PhoneIndex__c = :toProcess.Phone AND MobileIndex__c = :toProcess.MobilePhone  LIMIT 1];
                     system.debug('toProcess.existLead: '+existLead);
                    if(existLead.size()>0 ){
                        toProcess.addError('This lead already exist in system.');
                    }
                } 
            }

        }
    }else if(Trigger.isAfter){
        if(Trigger.isInsert){
```

Comment: Your trigger isn't properly 'bulkified'. You'll run into problems if it is called for more than 100 records - possibly earlier - because you run the SOQL query once for every inserted record which will lead to a "Too many SOQL queries: 101" very soon

Comment: Yes I have run into that with inserting big files but the duping still doesn't work even for importing say 2 leads in an excel file is that makes any difference

Comment: Excel?! Uh, oh! Can you confirm that it ever processes the code with the "if(toProcess.Phone != null || toProcess.MobilePhone != null){" block? I suspect that these fields are potentially never null when loaded from Excel. Maybe you also want to check for blank Strings. Because '' != null

Comment: We need that block you have quoted, I plan on putting another if statement for a different error if they are blank after this is fixed. Just this part of the trigger doesn' t work when using the dataloader.io(which is excel files). It works if you manually try and import a lead though.

Comment: You need to check for empty strings in that same if statement. I modified my answer to take this into account. If the fields loaded from Excel are not null but empty strings, your code above will not check for dupes.

Comment: It works in our sandbox but not production, what could be causing this?

Comment: You mean you still get the duplicates in production?

Comment: Ok after a bit more testing it looks likes it works but it only dupes against leads that have been created by the user doing the import which is obviously no good.

Comment: It also looks like it doesn't dupe against a manual created lead with the dataloader.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version which first reads all the possibly required existing Lead records into a Map for later use within the main processing loop. This solution uses one SOQL statement outside the loop.

```
trigger LeadTrigger on Lead (before insert, after insert, after update) {
    DateTime datetoSearch = DateTime.now().addDays(-14);
    List<Opportunity> oppList = New List<Opportunity>();
    List<Lead> leadList = New List<Lead>();
    List<Database.LeadConvert> lConverts = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();
    List<String> phoneNumbers = new List<String>();
    List<String> mobileNumbers = new List<String>();
    Map<String, Lead> existingLeads = new Map<String, Lead>();


    if(Trigger.isBefore){
        if(Trigger.isInsert){

            for(Lead toProcess : trigger.new){
                if(toProcess.Phone != null || toProcess.MobilePhone != null){
                    phoneNumbers.add(toProcess.Phone);
                    mobileNumbers.add(toProcess.MobilePhone);
                }
            }
            for (Lead existLead: [SELECT Id, PhoneIndex__c, MobileIndex__c FROM Lead 
                    WHERE PhoneIndex__c in :phoneNumbers AND MobileIndex__c in :mobileNumbers]) {
                existingLeads.put(existLead.PhoneIndex__c + '_' + existLead.MobileIndex__c, existLead);
            }

            for(Lead toProcess : trigger.new){
                boolean isCheck = false;               
                system.debug('toProcess.PostalCode: '+toProcess.PostalCode);
                system.debug('toProcess.State: '+toProcess.State);

                if((toProcess.Phone != null && toProcess.Phone.length() > 0) || 
                        (toProcess.MobilePhone != null && toProcess.MobilePhone.length() > 0) {
                    if(existingLeads.get(toProcess.Phone + '_' + toProcess.MobilePhone) != null ){
                        toProcess.addError('This lead already exist in system.');
                    }
                } 
            }

        }
    }else if(Trigger.isAfter){
        if(Trigger.isInsert){
```

Comment: Thanks Frank, I tried that but get the following error: LeadTrigger: Variable does not exist: existlead

Comment: That's probably the one in the debug statement, right? So I suggest you just delete that: system.debug('toProcess.existLead: '+existLead);

Comment: It should also be said that this code is not tested, it is meant as a hint on how to solve the too many SOQL query issues.